# Remote login to google

Tags: php, curl

I don't understand where is the problem on my code. when I try to login on google, its redirect me this page: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61416?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

I wants to login google then get back to `google.com`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v1/lookup");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Email=MY-EMAIL@gmail.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_exec($ch);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Passwd=MY-EMAIL-PASS');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

echo $output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: You need to read and send cookies in order to keep user logged. Check this page for an example: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch11_04.htm

Comment: when i use cookies, output return only login page

Comment: @Triby Please submit your solved answer

Comment: I don't have a solution, just that link as reference, sorry.

Comment: my code has anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, your code needs to read and send cookies to work.

Comment: i am not expert with curl, so i don't understand clearly